# Laravel jQuery, вывод данных в селект

Tags: jquery, laravel, select

Есть выборка из БД данные из которой подставляются в селект,но проблема в том, что этих селектов может быть несколько и надо в последующие селекты выводить данные из выборки исключая уже выбранные выше результаты.

Как это сделать? Понимаю, что нужно использовать JS, но как именно не понятно?

```
$cards переменная в которой хранится выборка.



@foreach ($cards as $card)
<option value="{{$card->id}}">{{$card->name}}</option>
@endforeach
```

---

это в первом селекте выводится, в последующих надо отфильтровать уже выбранные результаты.

Comment: Покажите кож где выводятся данные в селект. Напишите исходные данные и что нужно получить в итоге

Comment: я неверно выразился, я имел ввиду селект в смысле выпадающий список на фронте а не селект в выборке из базы данных

Comment: @Сергей, если я правильно понял, то вы хотите выбрать только уникальные значение, чтобы просто подставить в селект, да? Если так, то цитата: *Метод `distinct` указывает запросу возвратить только уникальные значения:*

Comment: есть выборка из БД в которой содержится два поля которые я вывожу на фронт, но это прокатывает только с первым селектом, потом мне надо без перезагрузки страницы исключить уже выбранные результаты в последующих селектах на фронте

Comment: @Сергей, хм, тогда этот вариант не подойдёт. А если просто перед селектом создать массив с данными и использовать [`array_unique`](http://www.php.su/array_unique)? А потом просто вывести..

Comment: сейчас добавлю код, без него непонятно получается

Comment: то есть получается надо как то передать выборку в массив JS и уже из него выводить данные

Comment: @Сергей, смотрите, возможно так сделайте: `foreach($cards as $card) $array[$card->id] = $card->name;`, а потом `foreach(array_unique($array) as $key => $value) { ... тут вывод селекта }`